# How do I write a reference in my reference list which has various places of publication with different editorials?

Tags: citations, reference-request

I am writing my reference list for my final paper and there is a book, which has different places of publication with different editorials in each one

Comment: So are you referencing a specific editorial (so reference that specific edition), or does it not matter which edition?

Answer (score 1):

You reference the one you actually read.